# What are the underlying differences among select, epoll, kqueue, and evport?

Tags: unix, redis, epoll, multiplexing, kqueue

I am reading Redis recently.
Redis implements a simple event-driven library based on I/O multiplexing.
Redis says it would choose the best multiplexing supported by the system, and gives the following code:

```
/* Include the best multiplexing layer supported by this system.
 * The following should be ordered by performances, descending. */
#ifdef HAVE_EVPORT
#include "ae_evport.c"
#else
    #ifdef HAVE_EPOLL
    #include "ae_epoll.c"
    #else
        #ifdef HAVE_KQUEUE
        #include "ae_kqueue.c"
        #else
        #include "ae_select.c"
        #endif
    #endif
#endif
```

I wanna know whether they have fundamental performance differences? If so, why?

Best regards

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In general, all Async I/O subsystems have different internals, but in current specific case these concrete async I/O libs are used to support as much platforms as possible. That is:

- *evport* = Solaris 10
- *epoll* = Linux
- *kqueue* = OS X, FreeBSD
- *select* = usually installed on **all** platforms as a `fallback`

`Evport`, `Epoll`, and `KQueue` have **O(1)** descriptor selection algorithm complexity, and they all use internal kernel space memory structures. Also they can serve **lots** (hundreds of thousands) file descriptors.

Apart the others, `select` can only serve **up to 1024** descriptors, and does full scan of descriptors (so every time it iterates all descriptors to chose one to work with), so the complexity is **O(n)**.

Comment: Thanks. I found this article helps. http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~sangjin/2012/12/21/epoll-vs-kqueue.html

Comment: Should be noted that Illumos (The open source Solaris derivative) also supports (Linux style) epoll: https://illumos.org/man/5/epoll